# How to I determine/ interpret values of autoranging multimter

Tags: batteries, capacity, discharge, voltage

I have an autoranging multimeter and many AA batteries.... how do I interpret the readings when deciding to keep or discard AA (1.5 volt) batteries?

Comment: This is not really an answer to the specific question.
Drop the multimeter and buy one of these: [http://www.ztsinc.com/minimbt.html](http://www.ztsinc.com/minimbt.html)
I use many alcaline batteries (an application where rechargeables are not an option) and it really works, flawless.

Answer (score 5):

Look up voltage curves for the chemistry of your batteries. Depends on the exact battery, but you can gauge how much power is left based on the voltage:

[image]

From this graph, when it reads 1.0V, there is roughly 20% power left, and when it reads 0.8V, roughly 5% power left. Of course, it's hard to extract 100% of the power from a battery, since many devices require a certain voltage level to operate, and when it drops too low, they cannot run. Depends on the design of the device.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful not to confuse voltage with the amount of charge left in a battery. The open circuit voltage of a battery probably changes very little until it's virtually dead. However, over the same period of time the internal resistance of the battery my increase a great deal. Also notice that in the interesting graph davr posted that it's for batteries discharging 500 mA. So that means if you have a nominal 1.5V battery, you will want to short it with 3 ohm load and measure the voltage. Careful, that means if you use a resistor, that resistor will need to be rated for greater than 3/4 Watts. This also means you are using up your charge during your test.

You might want to run an experiment yourself and short a battery with a load mimicking a likely current draw for your purpose, and logging the voltage.

Determining the charge left in a battery is a non-trivial problem. Many consumer products don't quite get battery monitoring right.

Comment: This is totally true.  Even in the best case of davr's graph, the voltage drop vs capacity stays fairly constant (just a few tenths of a volt), until the big drop off.  I've been bitten many times by AAs I thought were good until *wham* they go dead.  So you can do a "this is definitely bad" test, but it's hard to say "this battery is probably good for a while".

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming Alkaline batteries -- In the Energizer datasheets 
the capacity is specified down to 0.8V. I would discard them
if they are less the 0.8V. If it is a battery that I may not
check too often then I might set the limit at a volt or so.